# Use plink/ssh in a Batch

Tags: shell, batch-file, ssh, putty, plink

I try to connect from my local machine to a server with plink. From the server i need to connect to an other local mashine over ssh to perform some commands

my try is:

```
plink -load "puttyProfile" -pw password "ssh admin@address"
```

which works. But now i want to give the ssh an operation like this

```
plink -load "puttyProfile" -pw password "ssh admin@address "cd .."   "
```

my error looks very strange something like this

```
#< CLIXML <Objs Version="1.1.0.1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/powershell/2004/04"><Obj S="progress" ....
```

which goes on for a while.
Please give some advise =D
Greetings

Comment: Your error says `Powershell` but you used the `batch-file` tag.

Comment: Where do you execute your `plink` command line from?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t thought it would make a difference. plink is the putty application for console. Works same as ssh on Linux

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok got it myself..
on the last pc where i want to do the operations ssh was using powershell and not command prompt. It seems like powershell cant work with the list of operations given over ssh. i changed to command promp and it works bettet.
Also i need to change the inner " to '
chaining commands wasnt a problem ether when u use && the ; wont work

```
ssh admin@address "ssh admin2@address2 'cd ..  &&  dir'  ; echo hey "
```

Answer (score 0):

```bat
"C:\\Program Files\\PuTTY\\plink.exe" -ssh "10.164.107.11" -l "karan" -pw "3Wdgwqd@Ws" -m "command.txt"
```

in commands you can write:

```sh
cd / ;
cd /local/apps/coreservices-s3/;
echo -e "The file is present in\n ";

find . -type f -name "TextFile4*";

echo -e "The content of the file is :\n ";
find . -name "vccvdv6.txt" |xargs cat

echo -e "\n\n."
```